# How do I find the PID of the current instance of the Bash shell i'm using?

Tags: bash

How do I find the PID of the current instance of the Bash shell

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PROCCID

Answer (score 1):

Read `man bash`. It's either `$$` or `$BASHPID`, which differ in certain cases.